# Is there a way to dynamically set the max y axis value of 2 graphs to the same value in Quiver, to ensure a consistent scale for comparison?

Tags: aggregation, palantir-foundry

I am working on a Quiver dashboard and need to have 2 graphs side by side which are driven by 2 different filters and which use the same y axis max value to allow for comparison. I can create numeric aggregation objects using simple metrics of Max for each graph input object, but don't know how to combine these to do an equivalent of "if a>b then a else b" to then use as the max value in the graphs.
Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible natively in Quiver yet. If you need this, you should raise a feature request with your Palantir team.

As a workaround for now, you could do one of:

- Set the max values manually for each of the graphs to a number you expect to be the reasonable maximum for both. You can do this in your chart's configuration: the 'Display' tab > 'Scale Options' > 'Maximum Bound' > 'Max' > enter the value.
- Plot both series on the same graph, and share the axes.
- Add a 'fake' precomputed series which is just the max value, and style the series so it's hidden (e.g. white line on white background).